# NSPredicate to check property of first 5 objects in a Core Data Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am looking to create a predicate that can check the `TypeID` of the first 5 objects in a `Core Data` relationship.

Here is what I am trying, but it doesn't work:

```
int num = 5;
NSMutableArray *predicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ AND logs[%i].TypeID == 3", items, i]];

}
```

This gives the error:

> error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
>   < NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x281837aa0 > , Unsupported function
>   expression logs[0].TypeID with userInfo of (null) CoreData:
>   error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
>   < NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x281837aa0 > , Unsupported function
>   expression logs[0].TypeID with userInfo of (null)

I realize I am probably doing this wrong, so is there a different way that I could be doing this using `NSPredicate`?

Comment: What’s logs? Your object has a property logs?

Comment: The type of a relationship is usually a `Set` which is unordered. So the *first 5 objects* can be different. You need to apply **one** predicate which sorts the set and filters the objects.

Comment: @E.Coms Yes it does. Logs is a relationship of the `SELF` object.

Comment: @vadian Yes it is a `Set`. How can a predicate sort and filter at the same time?

Comment: You could use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the fetch results, then filter. Or you could add a sort index in your Core Data model, and use that in your predicate.

Comment: A fetch request can have a predicate and multiple sort descriptors at the same time.

Comment: Do you want any of the first 5 logs to have typeid == 3, or all of them?

Answer (score 0):

if you want only fetch 5. Set fetchLimit to 5. Maybe the following code can not run right away, but the principle is same. You can add a property or get function to assign the "logs.TypeID" like -(Int)myID {return logs[0].TypeID;} then "SELF IN %@ AND myID == 3" would solve the problem.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity name" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ AND logs.TypeID == 3", items];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand the questions, but I don’t think it’s possible to do what you asked, at least not as worded.   It doesn’t seem like it would be possible to inspect only five objects in the relationship and stop there, returning any number of matches or none at all, even if there are more in the database.

However, and I think this may be what you were getting at, it *is* possible to find five objects that are both in the `items` set and have at least one `log` with a `typeID == 3`.   It can be done similar to what E.Coms proposed, except you need a subquery to handle the relationship. (I am assuming logs is a to-many relationship, either one-to-many or many-to-many).

Note that the following code has not been tested:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity name" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ AND SUBQUERY(logs, $log, $log.typeID == 3).@count != 0", items];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {

}
```